# Jira -Python Error

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, jira, python-jira

I was trying to run this jira script and its been a couple of hours can't
quite figure out what the issue is. can someone help me. I get the following 
error.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "mytest.py", line 2, in

from jira.client import JIRA

ImportError: No module named 'jira'

```
 from jira.client import JIRA
import json
import csv

options = {'server':  'https://jira.myjira.com/', 'verify':False}

jira = JIRA(options)

issues = jira.search_issues('project=DCE and created > -365d ORDER BY key      
DESC',maxResults=10000,fields='id,key,customfield')

f = open("test.csv", "w",newline="")
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='|')


for issue in issues:
fl =    
 [issue.key,issue.fields.status.name,issue.fields.customfield]
writer.writerow(fl)

f.close()
```

Comment: Personally, I solved with this python3.10 -m pip install atlassian-python-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python can't see that the jira module is installed.

http://pythonhosted.org/jira/#installation

Answer (score 4):

- Please, try `pip install jira`
- If not, please check if your script is named **jira.py**... If so, rename it to another name such as **my-test-jira.py** or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install using **pip install jira** or **easy_install jira**

Answer (score 1):

The correct code for importing Jira is:

```
from jira import JIRA
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple manual steps to fix this issue which I followed:

Go to Settings-> Python Interpreter -> Click on Plus (+) sign from left nav (that says "Install") beside "Latest version" column .

Type "jira" and choose it's available versions and Click on button "Install Package" and wait for its installation.